# Regain ability to click button in form

Tags: powershell, winforms, button, controls

I'm trying to get a form to show a background progress of the script and have the ability to close it via button after the script completes. The TextBox refreshes as supposed but I cannot click the button after. Please advise.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function ButtonClick
{
    $mainForm.Close()
}

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$button = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$button.Location = '10, 10'
$button.Name = "buttonGo"
$button.Size = '75, 25'
$button.TabIndex = 0
$button.Text = "&Go"
$button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$button.Add_Click({ButtonClick})

$textBoxDisplay = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$textBoxDisplay.Location = '12, 50'
$textBoxDisplay.Multiline = $true
$textBoxDisplay.Name = "textBoxDisplay"
$textBoxDisplay.Size = '470, 150'
$textBoxDisplay.TabIndex = 1

$mainForm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$mainForm.Size = '500, 250'
$mainForm.Controls.Add($button)
$mainForm.Controls.Add($textBoxDisplay)
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$mainForm.Name = "mainForm"
$mainForm.Text = "Show Get-NetConnectionProfile Output"

cls
$mainForm.Show()


$1 = @([pscustomobject]@{name = 'Time'},
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Zenek'},
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'NetEx'},
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Busy'},
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Shorts'})

$1|%{$textBoxDisplay.Text += "$($_.name) already present`r`n"; $textBoxDisplay.Refresh(); Start-Sleep -s 2}
```

Comment: You're calling `$mainForm.Show()` instead of `$mainForm.ShowDialog()`, also this call should be the last in your code (after the `$1|%{$textBoxDisplay.Text += ...`)

Comment: $mainForm.ShowDialog()gives me back control, true, but it shows already complete version of `$textBoxDisplay.Text`. What I want is for it to show every mew line, as in my code in the post above.

Comment: I don't understand what that means sorry

Comment: If you run the code from the original post it will add a line to TextBox every two seconds. I want to retain that.
If I place $mainForm.ShowDialog() at the end, oall five of the line are placed.

Comment: Now I see what you meant, I didn't see that `Start-Sleep` in your code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, instead of [`.Show()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-control-show) which will simply display your form and regain control of your thread you want to call [`.ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-form-showdialog) instead which blocks the threads and refreshes the form automatically.

Regarding adding an item each 2 seconds to your `TextBox`, you can use the [Form's `Shown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) event:

```bash
$mainForm.Add_Shown({
    @(
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Time'}
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Zenek'}
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'NetEx'}
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Busy'}
        [pscustomobject]@{name = 'Shorts'}
    ) | ForEach-Object {
        $textBoxDisplay.Text += "$($_.name) already present`r`n"
        Start-Sleep 2
    }
})

$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: And now everything works as intended. I was trying to implement Add_Shown but couldn't get it to work. Thank you